# Send JSON data with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Why code below sent data as `City=Moscow&Age=25` instead of JSON format?

```
var arr = {City:'Moscow', Age:25};
$.ajax(
   {
        url: "Ajax.ashx",
        type: "POST",
        data: arr,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: dataType is what's returned, not what is sent!

Comment: Try to put 'dataType' before data... not sure.

Comment: To prevent `data` from being converted to query string format set `processData: false`.  See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#sending-data-to-server

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Because you haven't specified neither request content type, nor correct JSON request. Here's the correct way to send a JSON request:

```
var arr = { City: 'Moscow', Age: 25 };
$.ajax({
    url: 'Ajax.ashx',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(arr),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

Things to notice:

- Usage of the `JSON.stringify` method to convert a javascript object into a JSON string which is native and built-into modern browsers. If you want to support older browsers you might need to include [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html)
- Specifying the request content type using the `contentType` property in order to indicate to the server the intent of sending a JSON request
- The `dataType: 'json'` property is used for the response type you expect from the server. jQuery is intelligent enough to *guess* it from the server `Content-Type` response header. So if you have a web server which respects more or less the HTTP protocol and responds with `Content-Type: application/json` to your request jQuery will automatically parse the response into a javascript object into the `success` callback so that you don't need to specify the `dataType` property.

Things to be careful about:

- What you call `arr` is **not an array**. It is a javascript object with properties (`City` and `Age`). Arrays are denoted with `[]` in javascript. For example `[{ City: 'Moscow', Age: 25 }, { City: 'Paris', Age: 30 }]` is an array of 2 objects.

Comment: Hi I have tested it in my code but it doesn't work http://pastie.org/pastes/7975866/text why?

Comment: Technically objects in JavaScript are just associative arrays. so while it is confusing to do so, calling an object an array in JavaScript is not a mistake.
For more information see: [JavaScript Data Structures](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/1441-javascript-data-structures-the-associative-array.html)

Comment: @Nadav the fact that it's confusing is _more than enough_ reason not to do it.

Answer (score 10):

Because by default jQuery serializes objects passed as the `data` parameter to `$.ajax`.  It uses [`$.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param) to convert the data to a query string.

From the jQuery docs for [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax):

> [the `data` argument] is converted to a query string, if not already a string

If you want to send JSON, you'll have to encode it yourself:

```
data: JSON.stringify(arr);
```

Note that `JSON.stringify` is only present in modern browsers. For legacy support, look into [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a short convenience function for posting JSON.

```
$.postJSON = function(url, data, success, args) {
  args = $.extend({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true,
    success: success
  }, args);
  return $.ajax(args);
};

$.postJSON('test/url', data, function(result) {
  console.log('result', result);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the correct content type and stringify your object.

```
var arr = {City:'Moscow', Age:25};
$.ajax({
    url: "Ajax.ashx",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(arr),
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It gets serialized so that the URI can read the name value pairs in the POST request by default. You could try setting processData:false to your list of params. Not sure if that would help.