# Spring and jQuery POST crossdomain

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring 3.2.2 and jQuery.

Everything works fine in local. I made a CORS filter which also works fine.

Every service methods called from another host are working except one. Actually, this is the only method which use `@RequestBody` and `$.toJSON` / `contentType` at client side.

Spring side :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/requestOrder", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Object requestOrder(@RequestBody OrderViewModel order) throws NamingException {
    ...
}
```

jQuery side :

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : serviceUrl + 'requestOrder',
    crossDomain : true,
    data : $.toJSON({ ...orderdata... }),
    contentType : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
});
```

Chrome's console log :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://REMOTE_HOST/project/service/requestOrder. The request was redirected to 'https://REMOTE_HOST/project/;jsessionid=84781b083f5305ffa22a0adae0a6', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.
```

HTTP headers :

```
Request URL:https://.../requestOrder
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:302 Moved Temporarily
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:...
Origin:http://...
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://...
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36
```

I don't see `Content-Type` which should be set... Request method is `OPTIONS` ?!

This let me think that the issue is coming from Spring but this is actually working in local...

I would be pleased to get some help.

Comment: Can you post the full URL's of redirects on the error message?

Comment: Actually not the correct ones but I'll rename.

Comment: Try adding produces="application/json" to your RequestMapping

Comment: And if is a Cross domaing JSON, you might need to use JSONP. Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about

Comment: `produces="application/json"` is already on the controller - sorry I did not mention it. Going to try with JSONP.

Comment: JSONP will do the magic trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution :

I changed the parameter of my Spring mvc method to `String` and `RequestBody` to `RequestParam` :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/requestOrder", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Object requestOrder(@RequestParam("order") String orderJson) {
```

Ajax call is now like this :

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : serviceUrl + 'requestOrder',
    crossDomain : true,
    data : { order : $.toJSON({ ...orderdata... }) },
    contentType : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
});
```

And in the `requestOrder` method, I'm parsing json manually :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
OrderViewModel order = mapper.readValue(orderJson, OrderViewModel.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the content type mapping. Try this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/requestOrder", method = RequestMethod.POST, ,headers="Content-Type=application/json")
```

For the JQuery part 
it looks like you need to set both

```
 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
```

Look at [Send JSON data with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587221/send-json-data-with-jquery)

Comment: Not working. Actually, the header `Content-Type` is not even sent by jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Seens like you need to use JSONP, if this request is beeing made to another domain.

Check here:
[What is JSONP all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but actually, I'm already using CORS.

Comment: And with JSONP, the server throw a `415 Unsupported Media Type` :(