# jQuery Json via Ajax strange String behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Something strange happens: when i want to post a string "??" via ajax to the server

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: path,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: JSON.stringify({
    text: "??"
  })
});
```

it allways produces something like that in request to the server:

```
{"text":"jQuery21109622253710404038_1411696744993"}:
```

What is happening here? What the problem with double ? ?

Comment: if you send one question mark it goes through?

Comment: try it without the stringify.  You don't really need it unless you want to send an object inside data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the content type;

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: path,
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', //<--This line
  data: JSON.stringify({
    text: "??"
  })
});
```

Check this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587221/send-json-data-with-jquery)

Let me know if it works

Comment: yeah, that did the trick for me! thanks a lot! i thought that would be handled if i specify the datatype:json...

Comment: that happens, dataType is for the client to use on the response from the server

Answer (score 0):

Do not use JSON.stringify for data. It should work fine after removing that. See the code below.

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'http://localhost/rnd/ajax.php',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: {text: "??"}
});
```