# How to make such a structure in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to JS. And have a basic silly doubt. Please bear with me.I want to send a request of the form:

```
{"user":{"username":"myuser","password":"mypass","role":"myrole"}, "organization":"org_name"}
```

such that the user object can be access by `req.body.user` and organisation can be accessed by `req.body.organization`.

But when I'm sending this request:

it translates to-

```
{
 "user[username]": "myuser",
 "user[password]": "mypass",
 "user[role]": "myrole",
 "organization": "org_name"
}
```

When I just send

```
{"user":{"username":"myuser","password":"mypass","role":"myrole"}}
```

then I can access using `req.body.user`, but not the way mentioned above. Why is this so?

How can I send the request now such that I can access the `request.body.user` and `req.body.organization` properly?

**EDIT**:

This is how the request is sent. Front end: ember, backend node/express:

```
Ember.$.post("http://"+window.location.hostname+":3000/api/organizations/customer",{"user":{"username":"myuser","password":"mypass","role":"myrole"}, "organization":"org_name"},function(data){ 
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data),null, " "); 
        });
```

Receiving side:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body,null," "));
```

I am trying to create the user but req.body.user is undefined. Though I can use user[username]  and proceed, but that s now how I want to do

Comment: it happening because in `name` attribute of your textfield in html you put 'user[username]' ...

Comment: How is this request translated? That's a very strange form to translate the first request into.

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain: this happens even when I try using REST client.

Comment: @EvanKnowles I just tried to print the request body in the server: `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body,null," "));`

Comment: How exactly are you sending the data? Are you setting the datatype to JSON? Can you post the code you're using to send the data to the server?

Comment: Please post both the code that sends the data and the code that receives it.

Comment: @ChristianVarga :Please check the edit now

Comment: @Christian Varga: -> Default: Intelligent Guess  (xml, json, script, text, html )

Comment: You aren't sending JSON to the server. You need to use JSON.stringify on the data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587221/send-json-data-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Christian Varga's answer to this post, I could further dive in. Though the problem was still not solved, but it gave some insight of how can that be solved.

This is what I did next for such a structure. As per his suggestion, I used `JSON.stringify` but at a different place:

```
Ember.$.post("http://"+window.location.hostname+":3000/api/organizations/customer",{"user":JSON.stringify({"username":"myuser","password":"mypass","role":"myrole"}), "organization":"org_name"},function(data){ 
  console.log(data); 
});
```

On the backend server side I could then receive `req.body.user`. But the req.body.user was stringified JSON. To further access this inner JSON, I had to use `JSON.parse`.

Though this worked, but I was looking for more better solution, since this backend change worked for my front end implementation, but was failing for RESTClient.

I understood I need to pass the contentType of the data to be sent in the post request. I could not find `$.post` argument for contentType. So then I used `$.ajax` call.

```
Ember.$.ajax({
               url: "http://"+window.location.hostname+":3000/api/organizations/customer",
               type:"POST",
               data: JSON.stringify({user:{username:username,password:password,role:role}, organization_id:organization_id}),
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               dataType:"json",
               success: function(data){ 
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data),null, " "); 
                 }
        });
```

where the `username, password, role, organization_id` are already assigned variables.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't sending JSON to the server. Passing an object in as `data` doesn't send it as an object; it simply gets converted to a query string [[source](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)]. If you want to send JSON, you need to use JSON.stringify on the data that you **send**, not the data you receive.

```
Ember.$.post("http://"+window.location.hostname+":3000/api/organizations/customer",JSON.stringify({"user":{"username":"myuser","password":"mypass","role":"myrole"}, "organization":"org_name"}),function(data){ 
  console.log(data); 
});
```

Comment: It does not work properly. It has stringified in a different way. When I print `console.log(req.body);` this is what i get on the server side : 
`{ '{"user":{"username":"myuser","password":"mypass","role":"myrole"},"organization":"org_name"}': ' ' }`
it seems it has considered whole string as the key and then `'` `'` as the value and still the request.body.user is undefined