# How to make an AJAX call to GraphHopper Route Optimization API?

Tags: javascript, ajax, graphhopper

I'm trying to use GraphHopper Route Optimization API for solving VRP with pickups and deliveries. I want to test it with an example from https://graphhopper.com/dashboard/#/editor. My request goes like this:

```js
var vrp = {
      "vehicles": [
        {
          "vehicle_id": "my_vehicle",
          "start_address": {
            "location_id": "berlin",
            "lon": 13.406,
            "lat": 52.537
          }
        }
      ],
      "services": [
        {
          "id": "hamburg",
          "name": "visit_hamburg",
          "address": {
            "location_id": "hamburg",
            "lon": 9.999,
            "lat": 53.552
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "munich",
          "name": "visit_munich",
          "address": {
            "location_id": "munich",
            "lon": 11.57,
            "lat": 48.145
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "cologne",
          "name": "visit_cologne",
          "address": {
            "location_id": "cologne",
            "lon": 6.957,
            "lat": 50.936
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "frankfurt",
          "name": "visit_frankfurt",
          "address": {
            "location_id": "frankfurt",
            "lon": 8.67,
            "lat": 50.109
          }
        }
      ]
    };

    $.ajax({
    beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
    },
    type: "POST",
    url: 'https://graphhopper.com/api/1/vrp/optimize?key=[...]',       
    data: vrp,               
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(json){
       console.log(json);
    }});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I get the following response:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJSyq.png)

Waht may be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'have found solution in another so-question [Send JSON data with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587221/send-json-data-with-jquery).

Just use `data: JSON.stringify(vrp)`