# Python Flask - request.json returns None Type instead of json dictionary

Tags: python, json, flask

I'm writing a very simple demo webapp, and I can't seem to pass a json object from *js* to *python* using *ajax*.

I've tried a number of suggestions from people on so with similar problems, such as using `.get_json()` instead of `.json`, passing the object without using `JSON.stringify` in the javascript, etc.

Any idea what piece I'm missing here?

**Javascript**

```
var run_method = function(){

  var data1 = {"word":"hello"}
  console.log("Before " + data1);
  $.ajax({
      url : "/examplemethod",
      type : "POST",
      data : data1//JSON.stringify(data1)
  })
  .done(function(data){
      var data = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(data);

  });
}
```

**Python**

```
@app.route("/examplemethod", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def example_method():
    global data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print request
        data = request.json
        print "data", data
    return "after "+ data["word"]
```

Every variation I have tried of this gives a *500 Error*, and

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Obviously, that is because data is supposed to be an `dictionary/json`, not `None`. But how to I get it to return as a dictionary?

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: yes, I did - Thanks. However, It did not seem to fix anything.

Comment: Your answer did not solve my problem, so I did not accept it. I ended up figuring it out, but not using what you described here. Sorry I don't have the time to dig up that code and go into further detail.

Comment: If you solved your problem, you should post your solution.

Answer (score 8):

Because you are not sending JSON, to the flask app (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570747/jquery-posting-json) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587221/send-json-data-with-jquery)). Your current code results in a standard urlencoded form post. Which in turn results in an entry being populated in `request.form`

```
 request.form.get('word')
```

Switch to a json post as per the guidelines in the above Q&As to access the data through request.json.

Answer (score 0):

the data is likely not flowing to json if you are getting `None`, so you should jsonify the data. It will be coming in in the form of `form`.

```
from flask import jsonify

@app.route("/examplemethod", methods=['POST'])
def example_method():
    data = jsonify(request.form).json
    print(data) #will be in the form a json dict
    return data['foo-key'] #can retrieve specific items with their key-pairs
```