# Client submitted invalid JSON: lexical error: invalid string in json text.↵

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, http-status-code-400

I have an ajax POST method that, despite what I am sending to the server, is apparently appending a '↵' character to the value field. My code:

```
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   type: "POST",
   data: {"name" : "lol"},
   dataType : "json",
   contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});
```

The error returned is error code 400 `"Client submitted invalid JSON: lexical error: invalid string in json text.↵"` and the console reports that this `name=lol↵` is the data being sent.

Comment: Since it is an error on the backend side: what language are you using for the backend? PHP? Java? What frameworks?

Comment: I am making a request to the GroupMe API; as for the server that this site is running on, it's an Nginx on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: I see. Even though it might be not needed, but does GroupMe require an API key that you are missing?

Comment: It does and the key is incorporated in the url variable. Hmm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just read the error message again and checked with the docs [here](https://dev.groupme.com/docs/v3).

What you need to do is to send your request in JSON format, not as form-data. You specified the right contentType, but you need to *convert your data* using `JSON.stringify`

Look at [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6587249/881032) for a possible solution.
In your case it would be something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        name: 'lol',
    }),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
});
```

I hope that works for you. If this didn't work either, I would check with the docs at [dev.groupme.com](https://dev.groupme.com/docs/v3). Maybe you have misspelled some of the JSON fields?

Comment: Thank you so much!!! :) As a relative beginner, I really appreciate this!