# HTTP Status 415 Json and Jersey js to java

Tags: javascript, java, json, jersey

I'm having some troubles setting up my rest service.
I have a js script that collects data from a form, creates a json and sends it throug ajax request to the web service.
The problem is that I only got as response: "HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type"

Here is some code:

```
Js code for sending request:


    function sendRequest(){
        var json = json_prepare();
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('json', json);
        $.ajax({
         url : 'webapi/tool/insert/data',
         type : 'POST',
         data : formData,
         cache : false,
         contentType : 'application/json',
         processData : false,
         success : function(data, textStatusm, jqXHR){
          console.log("tutto ok");
         },
         error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
          console.log()("error")
         }
        });
       }
```

JAVA code of the web service:

```
 @POST
    @Path("/insert/data")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public Response insertEvent(Request request) throws Exception{
        //deve ricevere un oggetto json con tutti i parametri dell'evento
        log.debug(request.event.descrizione);
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity("Ricevuto").build();
    }
```

The Request object is so defined:

```
  public class Request {
    Event event;
    Gallery gallery;
    List<Activity> activity;

}
```

Comment: Your endpoint consumes `application/json`, did you try changing the `contentType` attribute in the ajax object from false to `application/json` ?

Comment: Yes Vitor, I've tryed but nothing changes... :(

Comment: Made some search, maybe this thread can help more: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587221/send-json-data-with-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587221/send-json-data-with-jquery)

Comment: Replace contenttype:"application/json" and check

Comment: Did you try `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED` instead of `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` in your Java code? Because when you're sending a POST request, the MIME type is probably `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: Mincong I've tried your solution but it seems not works.

Comment: Raja, I didn't understand what do you mean, because I've already that content type. Could you be more clear showing me where made the changes? :)