# Unable to get form posted JSON object data through AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am making a register form and submitting data through ajax and receiving posted data through **$input = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));**

No values are received on the server, returning null back in response.

This is my AJAX code : 
On submission of form this function is called and all inputs are received in **formData object**

```
function register() {
  var formData={
    h_no:$('input[name=h_no]').val(),
    h_name:$('input[name=h_name]').val(),
    total_rooms:$('input[name=total_rooms]').val(),
    total_blocks:$('input[name=total_blocks]').val(),
    h_id:$('input[name=h_id]').val(),
    pwd:$('input[name=pwd]').val(),
    c_pwd:$('input[name=c_pwd]').val(),
  }
  console.log(formData);
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'../api/hostels/register.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data:formData,
    success:function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
}
```

This is my `PHP code` : 
Here I am receive JSON data and decoding it to process and returning JSON response back

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

$input = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));


/* application code is written here */

echo json_encode($input);
```

**Output of this is coming null**

Comment: Because attribute `dataType:json` __does not mean__ that you send json to server.

Comment: then how can I post this json to server

Comment: Data posted to server as a simple array. Use `$_POST` for example. And btw, you don't have any json on client. You have a javascript object, and it is not json.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587221/send-json-data-with-jquery which answers the same question

Comment: ok. can I post string like this **query=hello&q=hi** and receive it in json on server

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.stringify(formData)` to post the data.