# Jquery not sending data to server

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using a common ajax function to handle my `HttpPost,HttpGet` request. But I am unable to pass parameter to the server through the ajax request.

Any help will be highly appreciated

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnEdit", function () {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var url = $("#btnShowModal").data('url');

    ajaxOperation(url, 'GET', null, id, showModal);                
});

function ajaxOperation(url, httpVerb, dataType, dataToSend,  callback) {
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: httpVerb,
    datatype: dataType,
    data: dataToSend,
    success: function (data) {

        if (callback != undefined) {
            callback(data)
        }
    },
    error: function (e) {
        toastr.error("Unexpected error");
    }
});
}
```

On the server I am getting id as null

Comment: When is your `id` null? In your Javascript or on your server?

Comment: Pretty sure you need to pass `ajaxOperation(url, 'GET', null, {id: id}, showModal);`

Comment: On the server side

Comment: @AlonEitan how about form data

Comment: calling ajaxOperation(url, httpVerb, dataType, {"id":id},  callback) should work. You need to transmit both the name and value of "id".

Comment: @ksg Could work too AFAIK, but simple object should do the trick, if you want to get the parameter passed as `id` on the server

Comment: @AlonEitan should we pass it as a variable like var id="{id:'+id+'}"

Comment: @ksg NO: `var id = {id: $(this).data('id')};` and then you just pass it as you currently do (`ajaxOperation(url, 'GET', null, id, showModal);`)

Comment: Indeed, as @AlonEitan mentioned it, you need to pass your data as an object, and you also need to `JSON.stringify` it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587221/send-json-data-with-jquery#6587249

Comment: @PhilippeSultan  `JSON.stringify` did not work for me but as @Alon mentioned method did

Comment: @ksg So you're fine then - You managed to fix the issue and pass the parameter to the server?