# jQuery post not sending proper JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have some [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) that should `POST` [json](/questions/tagged/json) login data to a back end (using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)).

```
var dataObj = {};
dataObj["email"] = email;
dataObj["password"] = password;
postdata = JSON.stringify(dataObj);
request.controllers.LoginController.login()
  .ajax({
    data: postdata
  })
  .then(function(data) { ...
```

The code above posts the following (with an incorrect colon at the end), and is posted as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

```
{"email":"myemail@example.com","password":"mypass"}:
```

It should be without the colon at the end, and be posted as `application/json`.

Would like to know where my mistake is.   If I specify the contentType and other things from ["Send JSON data with jQuery"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587221/send-json-data-with-jquery), it makes no difference, so this is not a duplicate of that.

```
request.controllers.LoginController.login()
 .ajax({
       data: JSON.stringify(dataObj),
       contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
       dataType: 'json',
       async: false,
       processData: false
    })
```

The problem is that when it gets to the ajax function it looks like this:

```
"{"email":"myemail@example.com","password":"mypass"}"
```

Comment: Your data format does not match your `Content-type`

Comment: But where does it go wrong?

Comment: Looks right to me. How are you reading the request data on the server-side?