# how to send object from jquery to aspnet webapi controller?

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-web-api

I tried to send object as json  to controller in post method but it's raise error.
what's to do?(attatched this relvant code):

```
    public class user
    {
        public string username;
        public string password;
    }
    // POST: api/User
    public void Post(user u)
    {
        if (!database_layer.create_user(u.username, u.password))
        { throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest); }
    }
```

Comment: Please post the error you received

Comment: We also need to see your JS code which sends the request too, please

Comment: You probably want `Post([FromBody]user u)` but it will depend very much on how you're making the call and what the error is.

Comment: I sent the  relevant JS code

Answer (score 0):

If your data is to be send as JSON you need to serialize it before it is send. Replace `data:user` with

```
data: JSON.stringify(user)
```

See one of the following already asked questions:

1. [Send JSON data via POST (ajax) and receive json response from Controller (MVC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517071/send-json-data-via-post-ajax-and-receive-json-response-from-controller-mvc/8518646)
2. [Send JSON data with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587221/send-json-data-with-jquery)
3. [jQuery ajax, how to send JSON instead of QueryString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693947/jquery-ajax-how-to-send-json-instead-of-querystring)

Comment: Well I'm pleased I could help. You should mark the answer as correct So others can find it easily. Also on a little tangent, you should edit your original Post so that it contains the information you have now provided as an answer.